# How to store files offline that cannot be deleted by clearing the cache?

Tags: javascript, caching, local-storage, hybrid-mobile-app, offline-caching

**Background Info:**

- I am making a fitness app with Javascript, CSS, and HTML that allows users to create custom exercise routines.
- Android is the only required platform.
- The app will only require an internet connection for the initial download and optional updates and that is all I am able to host on my server.
- Therefore, I need to permanently store the user-made routines locally because my server cannot store/backup that data for them.

**The Problem:** If I just cache the routines, they will be permanently deleted if they clear their browser data.

**Undesirable Solutions:**

- Rewrite the entire app with Java in Android Studio
- Use PhoneGap (I was told that the required security updates were a pain)

**Therefore:** Is there a way for PWA's to store data on an android device that cannot be deleted by clearing browser data?

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is offer a backup as file download, and let users restore from it by reading it back in. Not exactly user friendly. Using react-native might be a slightly less undesirable 3rd option maybe?

Comment: Thank you. I'll try your backup file idea for now, but I'll leave the question open for other solutions.